# Not sure what isnt working for my google maps api example

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to run an example of google maps api on my tablet and it closes upon clicking. my device is running Android Version 4.1.2, Im not sure if this has anything to do with the problem

my manifest is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlemapsdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"

        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB0SiURk853k3By..." />
</application>
```

My layout file is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" /></RelativeLayout>
```

and my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map =((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the exception from the log.

Comment: 07-08 18:01:35.360: E/AndroidRuntime(6901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 18:01:35.360: E/AndroidRuntime(6901): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapsdemo/com.example.googlemapsdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What exactly do you mean with: it's closing? Do you mean that the app crashes or that the map disappears? Do you receive any error message in the log or debugger?

Comment: it crashes "unfortunately googlemapsdemo has stopped"

Comment: in the manifest under meta-data

Comment: Have you tried to Debug the application and step trough every line of code to find out at which line the app is crashing?

Comment: I tried running the app on 4.4 and it ran successfully. The only problem is that my tablet is 4.1.2 and it wont run with the same code. I've ran other apps on this tablet but is there any way around this?

Comment: @guevarak12 that is nowhere near to a complete stacktrace. Please post the full one in your question. We can't help you if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: 07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.googlemapsdemo/com.googlemapsdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(Act

Comment: 07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-08 18:47:53.839: E/AndroidRuntime(12012):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)